# Rails - URL re-write

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url-rewriting

I'm a newbe in Rails and have an application generates URLs like for example :

Started GET "**/ads?area_id=16**"
Started GET "**/ads?category_id=11**"
etc...

Is there a quick way in Rails to redefine those URLs like :
/MyAreaName
/MyCategoryName
etc...

If you know any article regarding this, thanks a lot to indicate it.
Thanks for your help

Comment: i dont know what exactly you are asking, why you are mentioning thinking sphinx ?

Comment: Hi Muhamamd, I'm talking about thinking sphinx because the URLs like ./ads?area_id=16 are generated by it.

I'm taking every potential solution if you have any.

Thanks

Comment: How are they generated? Can you show us some code? Thinking Sphinx has _no_ view-related code, hence Muhamamd's and my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to give good name your URLS you have to use [FriendlyId](https://github.com/FriendlyId/friendly_id)